# Node-red and Odoo ERP : Update odoo database from etable

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, odoo, node-red

I am working on node-red and trying to make some link with Odoo ERP. I just installed the [etable widget](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-ui-etable). Right now my flow works like this :

1. Inject a Customer
2. Search res.partner with customers conditions
3. By clicking on a button display all order with the state "draft" in an editable table
4. Would be to send to Odoo ERP all the modifications made in the editable table

Meaning that in my table I could change the amount of the draft order (`amount_order`) or the state (`state`) or the date of the order (`date_order`). And I want those changes to be sent to Odoo to update its database.

The connection with Odoo is made and works fine, I can display my orders in the table. The problem is that I can't send edits made (in the etable)to the Odoo database. In short I would like to update the Odoo database according to the edits made.

As I'm quite new to this I managed to get the data from Odoo but not to change it and then send new data to Odoo, would anyone know how to do it ?
[image: My flow]

Comment: How does this question relate to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71825080/connecting-node-red-and-odoo ?

Comment: Well what is asked on that question works just fine for me. The problem for is to update the odoo database from node-red. I already can display my orders, but if I make edits in the editable table, I want those edits to then be sent to odoo

Comment: Could you please provide MRC? Meaning if you can post your flow in JSON format so we can start from there :)

Comment: You can find the flow [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cpedroni/TG2/main/FLOW%20DRAFT%20ORDER.json) !

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used node-red, but have worked on similar scenarios in nodejs with the node-xmlrpc package. I thought maybe this would give you some idea to solve your problem.

Can you check if the model you are trying to update has write permissions set in your Odoo database ? It's been a while since I worked with Odoo, but I believe it should be in "Technical" > "Models".
The first step would be to set write permissions for the model and then use the node-xmlrpc package to update the model. Like, `odoo.execute_kw('res.partner', 'write', params, function (err, value)`

Also attaching link to [odoo-xmlrpc npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/odoo-xmlrpc) (documentation for various API methods is at the bottom) to help with understanding.
If this does not help you in anyway, I'm sorry, I could be of more help if this was in nodejs and not node-red!